# Scrapy : spider which doesn't work

Tags: python, scrapy

I'd like to scrap this website : [Meetic.fr](http://www.meetic.fr/) , the french version of  meetic.com .

The goal is to know how many people are connected (diplayed on the top of the page) after **authentification**.

Here is the spider : ( *[kobeddl, stack123456]* are real login if you want to try something)

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

from meetic.items import MeeticItem

class MeeticSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "meetic"
    allowed_domains = ["meetic.fr"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.meetic.fr/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        print 'TEST1'
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'log': 'kobeddl', 'pwd': 'stack123456'}, callback=self.after_login)]


    def after_login(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)  
            print 'TEST2'           
            return
    # We've successfully authenticated, let's have some fun!
        else:
            print 'TEST3'       
            return Request(url="http://www.meetic.fr/scheduler.php?url=", callback=self.parse_tastypage)

    def parse_tastypage(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = MeeticItem()
        item['nb'] = hxs.select('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/div/span').extract()
        print 'TEST4'
        return item
```

Here is the result in the command prompt :[image: result]
**EDIT :** as you can see, only the first  print statement `TEST1` is working.
I'm new with python and scrapy, so the reason is probably stupid.

I think there is a mistake in my spider, here : `if "authentication failed" in response.body:`
I found that in an other spider, but I don't know how to adjust it to this spider.

I also changed the user agent in the setting file 
`USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.7'`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the output, you will see a line that says "Filtered offsite request to...". That's because the action of the form is secure.meetic.com. You need to add that domain to the `allowed_domains` attribute on the spider, so that it doesn't get filtered.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source of the page of http://www.meetic.fr, you'll find that login form posts to `secure.meetic.com`:

```
<form id="formLogin" name="formLogin" action="https://secure.meetic.com/authent/secure.php" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:submitMeeticForm(this.id);">
```

So there's nothing strange there, you `POST` login data to `secure.meetic.com` and you get redirected back to your normal website after login.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. But why the spider doesn't return the item ?

Comment: Try putting a print statement into `parse_tastypage` to see if that function is ever called.

Comment: I putted a print statement in `parse_tastypage` and in `after_login` (both cases) and no one appear. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably update the question to reflect the second issue about why your code isn't working, but from inspecting the source HTML of the website, I think you may have mislabelled your username and password inputs in the form response:

```
<input id="log" name="log" type="hidden"/>
<input id="pwd" name="pwd" type="hidden"/>
```

Try modifying `parse` as follows:

```
def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'log': 'kobeddl', 'pwd': 'stack123456'}, callback=self.after_login)]
```

If not, then it might be 'txtHandle' and 'txtPassword' instead.

Comment: Thank you, Talvalin. I have changed it.

It's still not working and nothing change when I execute the spider. Do you thing that it will be very difficult to find a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Did you try using both combinations: 'log'/'pwd' and 'txtHandle'/'txtPassword'?

Comment: Yeah, there is the same result :/

English is not my native language, so if there is a big mistake in an important sentence, don't hesitate to tell me. Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have an idea or suggestion ? I'm stuck on this spider.